# How to measure time taken for QML item to appear on the screen since it was loaded?

Tags: qt, time, qml, loader, qquickitem

How can I measure time passed since the moment I have changed **source** or **sourceComponent** property of QML Loader to the moment visual item actually appeared on the screen (got painted)?

```
Loader {
    id: _loader
    source: "MyVisualItem.qml"
}
```

I already tried using statusChanged and Component.onCompleted signals but neither is accurate enough - it is easy to see that actual time is significantly greater.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the diagram in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#threaded-render-loop-threaded), `frameSwapped()` is your best bet:

[image]

You'll want to connect to that signal before setting `source`/`sourceComponent`, or directly afterwards. The first time it's called you can check the time it took to render it on screen. Don't forget to disconnect it afterwards. :)

Comment: The problem is figuring out which one is the first frame that is indeed rendering the item. That's not so simple with the deferred rendering architecture behind Qt Quick 2 -- technically speaking, it could happen *any* amount of frames after the component says it's complete.

Comment: I am not sure if there's any API for an accurate knowledge of this information; maybe the QML profiling hooks can be used to know when the renderer is gathering information out of an item's scenegraph nodes, and _possibly_ estimate then that the next frame rendered is going to be the first one showing the item. (In other words, this requires knowledge on how the renderer works internally.)

Comment: And other similar ways come to mind, e.g. a custom C++ item building a QSGNode that has the preprocess flag set -- the renderer is going to call `QSGNode::preprocess` on it, thus one can again estimate that the next frame is going to be rendered including that node.

Answer (score 1):

QML profiler should serve this issue (e.g. see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html)),

pure time measurement between source change and loading can be achieved 
by the [loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#status-prop) item itself:

```
Loader.Ready - the QML source has been loaded
Loader.Loading - the QML source is currently being loaded
```

and [loaded signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loaded-signal):

```
This signal is emitted when the status becomes Loader.Ready, or on successful initial load.    
The corresponding handler is onLoaded.
```

So measure time between source change occurence and onLoaded invocation

Comment: I tried using onLoaded signal, but the results are too inaccurate - it shows 40-60ms when actual time was 1200-1500ms. I can surely use this numbers for comparison (i.e. to see whether particular change has worsened transition time or not) but I would prefer to have values that are as close to real time as possible